# Trigger call function in the iOS app with the following logic

Tags: ios, iphone

We are making a topup solution, so we need a button in app(iOS) that triggers(call function) the following shortcode: enter *111*topupcode# then press the call button. For some reason, iOS can't handle the **# special characters. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the NSURL?

Comment: Apple does not allow apps to use these short code, for the reason that they can be misused to call expensive numbers and hide the real number being dialed.